# 'Create' button on ECS Service creation doesn't do anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I want to create an ECS service with ELB ('create new' option) and EC2 as backend. I am using AWS console and I amusing Frankfurt region.

When I click 'Create' button on the console, nothing happens! I cannot see any errors.

1. I tried the above with admin rights and even with the root account (!).
2. When I remove ELB, clicking 'Create' operates properly and the service is created.

Comment: Sounds like you need to file a ticket with AWS support.

Comment: If you open the browser console, do you see any network or JavaScript errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.